# Rendering attachment on visualforce page

Tags: attachment, pdf

I am having 2-3 attachment of different type (pdf/image/text etc). I want to display content of all the attachment on single visualforce page. Is it possible? If yes how can i go for it?

Answer (score 2):

How about looping over them and blatting out each one in an iframe?

**AccountAttachments.page**

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" sidebar="false">
    <apex:repeat value="{!Account.Attachments}" var="attachment">
        <h1>{!attachment.Name}</h1>
        <apex:iframe src="{!URLFOR($Action.Attachment.Download, attachment.Id)}" height="200" />
    </apex:repeat>
</apex:page>
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Its a good option but requirement is different. I want the attachments to display like a single pdf. suppose i have 1 image file, 1 pdf and 1 text file then i want to display them into a single pdf.

Comment: I just tested this in chrome and it correctly displays the files types that are listed in the question (pdf/image/text) but word and excel documents are not displayed. Instead they are downloaded automatically.

Comment: @Pankaj you might want to say that in the question then...

Comment: @BarCotter I see. Honestly, short of an applet or an extension I don't think it's gonna know how to render an .xls file etc. Chrome isn't Office, I feel that goes outside the bounds of behaviour a reasonable user could expect unfortunately.

Comment: @user320 I mean either in a single pdf or either continuously on vf page. in your current solution they seems like different files.

Comment: @bigassforce i added like above you mention code. but in site mode not working