# How to fetch latest 5 attachments from Contact Object and display in Visualforce page?

Tags: apex, visualforce, sfdcmobilesdk-android

I want to fetch latest 5 attachments from contact object and display those in visualforce page..
Please help me on this requirement.

Comment: Do you want to display the actual content of attachments in Visualforce?

Comment: yes same content from contact object

Answer (score 1):

You can query the attachment object and then display the result on your page.

```
List<Attachment> contactAttachment = [select Id, name from Attachment where parentId =:contact.id order By LastModifiedDate DESC limit 5];
```

In your page you can have a repeater to display attachments

```
<apex:repeat value="contactAttachment" var="att">
{!att.Name}
</apex:repeat>
```

Answer (score -1):

I got below from a different post. May be you can try it

[Rendering attachment on visualforce page](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/28268/rendering-attachment-on-visualforce-page)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.